# Why am I getting a deadlock when my code is accessed multiple times?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-deadlocks

In my c# code I have the following method that creates a document in the database, adds metadata regarding the document to the database and then updates some information regarding the date the repository was last updated.  This method is often called numerous times in quick succession as multiple file uploads are common.  However I am having problems with the code failing due to deadlock in sql server.

```
private IEnumerable<DocumentMetadata> CreateDoc(int? jobId, int?repositoryId, int? folderId, string documentTypeString,       IEnumerable<DocumentModel> files)
{
    if ((jobId == null && repositoryId == null) || (jobId != null && repositoryId != null))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Either job id or repository id must be specified");
        }
    using (var tran = new TransactionScope())
    {
        List<DocumentMetadata> newDocuments = new List<DocumentMetadata>();

        var documentType = GetDocumentTypeByPrefix(documentTypeString);

        if (folderId == null)
        {
            // Find the root folder
            var job = getJob(jobId);
            var rootFolder = getRootFolder(job);

            // If we can't find a root folder, create one
            if (rootFolder == null)
            {
                rootFolder = CreateRootDirectory(job);
            }

            folderId = rootFolder.FolderId;
        }

        User currentUser = _userService.GetCurrentUser();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var document = new Document() { Document1 = file.Data };
            var documentMetadata = new DocumentMetadata
            {
                Document = document,
                CreatedDate = file.CreatedDate,
                FileName = file.Filename,
                FileSize = file.Data.Length,
                FolderId = folderId,
                DocumentType = documentType,
                JobId = jobId,
                RepositoryId = repositoryId,
                User = currentUser
            };

            _unitOfWork.DocumentMetadata.Add(documentMetadata);
            newDocuments.Add(documentMetadata);
        }

        // set repository updated date 
        if (repositoryId != null)
        {
            DocumentRepository repo = GetDocumentRepository(repositoryId);
            if (repo != null)
            {
                repo.UpdatedDate = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now);
            }
        }

        _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        tran.Complete();

        return newDocuments;
    }
}
```

After some debugging it would appear that the updating of the repository id is causing the deadlock problem.  If I remove this code block outside of the transaction all files are saved with no errors.

Why would this code block

```
if (repositoryId != null)
        {
            DocumentRepository repo = GetDocumentRepository(repositoryId);
            if (repo != null)
            {
                repo.UpdatedDate = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now);
            }
        }
```

cause the deadlock? No other access is being made to the DocumentRepository table apart from in this method - as the locks are obtained in the same order surely there should be no deadlock?

What is it about this code that is leading to deadlock?

Updated: The code for GetDocumentRepository is:

```
 public DocumentRepository GetDocumentRepository(int repositoryId) 
 { 
     var result = DocumentRepositories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RepositoryId == repositoryId); return result; 
 }
```

Comment: I have earned reputation points off of checking if any of the objects used are not being disposed of properly.  This behaviour is typical of that root cause, and  I do not see a using statement or a call to dispose in the code. Deadlock is happening when during a second execution a physical resource is being accessed that had not been disposed of in the first execution.  Right now I do not have time to go through the code to write a formal answer but I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you show us the code for `DocumentRepository repo = GetDocumentRepository(repositoryId);`

Comment: `public DocumentRepository GetDocumentRepository(int repositoryId)
        {
            var result = DocumentRepositories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RepositoryId == repositoryId);
            return result;
        }`

Comment: @nothingman - It's much better that you edit your question to add code rather than put it in the comments. When you do add code, it's best to add the code at the end of your question so everyone can follow the changes easily.

Comment: @nothingman - I think you should also add the code that populates the `DocumentRepositories`.

Comment: @nothingman - And finally, can you please let us know what `_unitOfWork` is and why it appears to be a field-level variable? Usually a "unit of work" is created and closed each time it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the code without defining a transaction explicitly? Based on your code I would say that you are trying to read something that has been modified but not commited.
Another test you could do is to try to add a breakpoint in your code and try to get the DocumentRepository using READ UNCOMMITTED.